# Nestjs Jest test failed cannot find module from app.e2e-spec.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I am still new in nestjs and i don't understand what happen when i try to make a simple test with jest in nestjs test folder, i already notice the absolute path is not working on the import, so i used relative path, the rest of the app work fine but in app.e2e-spec.ts i got the error when i simply import the app.module.

app.module.ts

```
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module.js';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module.js';
import { PrismaModule } from './prisma/prisma.module.js';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
    PrismaModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Simple test in app.e2e-spec.ts

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppModule } from '../src/app.module.js'; //import relative path


describe('App end2end test', ()=> {
  beforeAll(async ()=> {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
     imports: [ AppModule ]  // this line
    
    }).compile();
  })
  it.todo('should pass');
})
```

I check the path there is no mistake, for this project i am using `Type: "Module"` in package.json and `"moduleResolution": "NodeNext",` in tsconfig.json.

setting in jest-e2e.json

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

ts.config.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2022",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
}
```

When i run npm run test:e2e i get this error :

> Cannot find module '../src/app.module.js' from 'app.e2e-spec.ts'

could it be the file extension with ts ? looks like the issue is the fact using "moduleResolution": "NodeNext" force me to add extension, while in the app when using "js" extention Typescript know it's a "ts" file, but this could be the issue on testing? what i am doing wrong or missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path should refer to a `.ts` file. You're currently addressing to `.js` file.

Change `../src/app.module.js` to `../src/app.module`.

---

**Updated:**

Ok, seems like Jest getting confused by `.js` files whenever you import them in `.ts` files, and couldn't resolve paths.

To fix this, you need to have some changes in `jest-e2e.json`:

```json
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": ["ts-jest", { "useESM": true }]
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^(\\.*/.*)\\.(j|t)s$": "$1"
  },
  "extensionsToTreatAsEsm": [".ts"]
}
```

Comment: I know it's not intuitive but you cannot import with ts extention with typescript, since an import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension.

Comment: I update the question, I can't remove it since the moduleResolution is set to **nodenext**

Comment: Would you please share the `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: ts.config file updated!

Comment: haha yea I just found the solution 5 min before you answer after searching into ts-jest documentation https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support, but since you have spend some time to solve this topic, i will accept your answer.